# Xamarin.Forms with FreshMVVM. Adding new property to FreshBasePageModel class

Tags: xamarin.forms, freshmvvm

My project (Xamarin.Forms with FreshMVVM) contains multiple pages and I need property isBusy. My PageModels inherit from FreshBasePageModel class. I'm looking for a way to extend FreshBasePageModel class to add IsBusy property.

Is there a way to do this? Multiple inheritance is not allowed in C#.
Using extension methods i only add methods (not properties).

There is an idea to add a new class (FreshBasePageModelExt) that inherits from the FreshBasePageModel class, and use this new class as a base class for my PageModels, but perhaps there is a more elegant solution.

Comment: creating your own custom base class is a pretty common pattern

Comment: To clarify Jason's suggestion: Your pages inherit from `MyBasePageModel`, which in turn inherits from `FreshBasePageModel`, and adds the desired property.

Answer (score 0):

Mine looks like this

```
    public class BaseViewModel : FreshBasePageModel
    {
            public bool IsBusy { get; set; }
            public string Title { get; set; }
    }
```

By creating this BaseViewModel and inheriting your viewModels from this will give you these attributes and then you have them in all your ViewModels.

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.